# foreground service does not persist when app is closed from background tray

Tags: android, foreground-service

I'm running foreground service and its notification disappears when the app is removed from recent apps tray.
I want to send data from database to server even when app is closed from recent app tray. How can I achieve this?

Code to display notification:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand executed");
    context = AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
    if (intent.getAction().equals("com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.startforeground")) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction("com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.main");
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ConnectivityCheckReceiver.class);
        previousIntent.setAction("com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.prev");
        PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                previousIntent, 0);

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Truiton Music Player")
                .setTicker("Truiton Music Player")
                .setContentText("My Music")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(
                        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
                        "Previous", ppreviousIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(101,
                notification);
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Show us relevant code

Comment: @fillobotto I've edited my question to add code.

Comment: This whole code should be placed inside  `onCreate` method of service

Comment: where to write the code to send data to server?

Comment: You should use  `onCreate` only for notification building and `startForeground`. The rest of your service logic is left unchanged. You still call service and elaborate the intent inside `onStartCommand`

Comment: Tried this too...but still the notification gets disapper after closing the app from recent app tray.

Comment: The Service's [onTaskRemoved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) method is triggered in this case. Maybe you could study using that to put the notification back.

Comment: is there anything other than startForeground service that will persist when app is removed from recent app list. I've even tried firebasejobdispatcher but that because of the custom os in some devices like redmi, it restricts schedular working.

Comment: @VishakhaGahukar did you solve it? Please share the solution

Comment: @Shruti See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate service for each persistent Foreground service/notification

Android Manifest:

```
<service android:directBootAware="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:name=".ForegroundService1">
    . . .
</service>
```

Your Service class:

```
public class ForegroundService1 extends android.app.Service
{
    static final int foregroundID = 1234567;
    static final string channelID = "Sync notification";
    ...

    @override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    {
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID)
                                                  .setContentTitle("Syncing ...")
                                                  .setContentText("Some more text")
                                                  .setSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.my_notification)
                                                  .setOngoing(true)
                                                  .setAutoCancel(false)
                                                  .build();

        //If Build >= Android Oreo
        //Create notification channel for channelID
        //@see https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#CreateChannel

        startForeground(foregroundID, notification);

        //Create Handler on separate thread, run your sync inside runnable
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
        handlerThread.start();
        Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
        Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override  
            public void run() {
                StartSync();
            }
        });

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void StartSync()
    {
        //Your code here which runs for a long while..

        //After you are done, stop the service and foreground notification
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

To start

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ForegroundService1.class);
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.StartForegroundService(context, i);
```